# Using on instead of live to hide a div with a specific id on link click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div with an id `#op-four` using `on` instead of `live`

```
$("#one").on("click", function() {
    $("#op-four").hide();
});​
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ythSA/ but it wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('.links-holder').on('click','#one',function() {
   $("#op-four").hide();
});
```

This use of the `.on` method replaces the now deprecated `.live()`.

```
$( document /or/ 'parent_el').on( 'some_event' , 'delegated_element', function(){
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: That works,thanks.How can i specify that i want to hide a paragraph with the id op-four and from a link with an id one?.

Comment: @flapjack that paragraph has an ID ? If the paragraph has already an ID there's no need to do: `p#one` as `ID`'s are already **unique**-per-page: that means that **only one element** can have the ID of #one.

Comment: @flapjack As I said, you'll have only ONE ID `op-four` in your page. (You cannot have more than one) , so there's no need to specify that your element is a `p` paragraph like `p#op-four`

Answer (score 1):

You've placed your code outside of your `ready` handler.  Move it inside and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/ythSA/2/

You were trying to attach a handler to `#one` before it actually existed.

Comment: @patrickgamer No it isn't.  The point of `on` **when used for delegation** is for dynamically loaded content, not for executing code before the dom is ready.

Comment: your statement says "try to attach handler to #one before it existing" - attaching listeners doesn't immediately execute code and you don't have to wait for document to be ready to define listeners using $.on(). I can see what you were trying to say, but I think your phrasing confuses binding listeners with execution

Comment: @patrickgamer But you do need to wait for document ready (or at least that dom element) unless you are using `$(document).on(` (usually a bad idea).  Whatever you are calling `on` on will have a listener attached when you call it.